# Where does OSX store the Desktop layout configuration info?

Tags: macos, finder, desktop

Since early Mac versions, I have been able to rearrange the icons on my desktop. Until I use one of the "Cleanup" options, they can be in pretty much random positions, even overlapping each other. The same layout of of file, directory, and app icons appears on all Desktop/Workspaces.

Where is that information on icon position stored?

What I would like to try doing is having the Desktop folder actually be a symlink that can be set to point to folders Desktop1, Desktop2, etc. I want to use the Current Key app (free) and it's use of AppleScript functions (`https://currentkey.com/room-change-alerts/`) to change that symlink on the fly, whenever I change desktops, so that I get a different set of icons for each desktop space that I'm in.

I would also like to preserve the layout of each set of desktop icons by also swapping the layout file.

Where can I find that layout file? (If it's a hiddent file in the Desktop directory then I might be home free.)

Thanks.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420090/copy-desktop-folder-and-preserve-layout

Comment: You may find it helpful to lock the symlinked Desktop folder as per [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372388/175188), to prevent it being reverted to a standard Desktop folder on reboot/login. I don't know how that would affect your plans with the Current Key app.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X/macOS stores Finder layout information (including desktop icon placement) within the .DS_Store file that's located inside the current directory.

Comment: Thanks, @AT0mic. That means it gets copied along with the rest of the Desktop folder. That's what I was hoping and didn't know where to look.
----
However, I was mistaken that I'm now "home free" because it turns out that the only way to get the desktop to refresh is to restart the Finder and that is not a speedy process, it has to rebuild every open Finder window too.

Comment: That restarting Finder problem has been solved by Clarity http://www.shirt-ediss.me/clarity/. Clarity works by moving everything out of the Desktop folder rather than replacing the whole folder, so restarting Finder is not needed. That means it gets a new set of icons (none, or restoring the original set, or whatever) fairly quickly. (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406287/automate-workspace-setup/410851#410851)

Comment: In modern macOS at least, this doesn't seem to be true. To prove my words: Create a folder `~/test`, open it, and create `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc` files there. Open Terminal and execute `ls -al ~/test`. Notice the modicication time at the `.DS_Store` line.

Comment: Wait a minute or two. Mark `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc` using color labels and, in addition, place them in some fancy way (for example, as a trianle) (this is assumed you use Icon view). Execute `ls -al ~/test` again. Notice the time at the `.DS_Store` line has not changed. Then add `aaa` a comment. Then execute `ls -al ~/test` again. Notice the time at the `.DS_Store` is now changed.

Comment: That is, `.DS_Store` is used to store comments, but not color labels or information about placement.

Comment: You can even `rm .DS_Store` and when you open this folder next time, all three files will stay on the same positions (that is, as a trianle).

Comment: Update: I have just realized that I have tested it with "regular" folder, that is, `~/test`, whereas the question itself and this answer are about `~/Desktop`, which might work differently. But: 1. Though I haven't tested, I'm sure there is no difference, 2. My personal interest is about "regular" folders (e.g., `~/test` or `~/Desktop/test`), not about `~/Desktop` only, and since I've started the bounty, I think it would be fair to expect the new, better answer will be about "regular" folders as well.

Comment: @jsx97 I found different behaviour with my `~/Desktop` folder. Testing only icon positions, `.DS_Store` updated with every  icon position change. However, when I tried the same in `~/test` the `.DS_Store` file updated only after making changes and quitting the Finder.

Comment: My Desktop is synced to iCloud which might explain the different behaviour. There's much more information in [this article](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/11/27/explainer-ds_store-files/) and its comment thread

Comment: So given that `.DS_Store` files do store icon positions for folders but for "normal" folders they aren't updated until the user quits the Finder, clearly that information is cached somewhere until the files get updated. Hopefully that answers your question @jsx97 ?