# Copy Desktop folder and preserve layout

Tags: desktop, file-transfer

How can I copy the Desktop folder from machine A to machine B and preserve the current icon layout?

I want to replicate the Desktop contents and layout in both machines. I mean the actual Desktop, not a Finder window when opened to `~/Desktop`.

I tried copying the `~/Desktop/.DS_Store` from A to B but it did not work.

I also tried to create a tar file with `~/Desktop` in A and the open the tar file in B, but it did not work: the layout wasn't replicated.

Comment: @user3439894 I read this as "icon layout on the desktop itself". Not sure this actually is stored in `.DS_Store`.

Comment: @user3439894, I've edited the question with some details.

Comment: @nohillside, if not in `.DS_Store`, where is the layout stored?

Comment: .DS_Store is for when you view the contents of ~/Desktop in a Finder window, not for the actual desktop itself. On top of that the desktop layout depends on the attached monitor, resolution, DPI and monitor count.

Comment: @John Keates, RE: ".DS_Store is for when you view the contents of ~/Desktop in a Finder window, not for the actual desktop itself." --  As it turns out the **~/Desktop/.DS_Store** _file_ does indeed contain the **Desktop** icon layout info, and while I didn't mention it in my answer, nonetheless, their positions adjusts automatically as the screen resolution changes, thus maintaining the same reletive layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can now confirm that the *layout* of *files* and or *folders* that are within the **~/Desktop** *folder* and show on the **Desktop** are indeed stored in the **~/Desktop/.DS_Store** *file*.

That said, the *layout* is also controlled by the **View Options** for the **Desktop** and the settings for both systems need to match. In other words, assuming **Sort By** it set to **None** on the source computer, it is also set to **None** on the destination computer.

Copy the source *files* and or *folders* to the **Desktop** of the destination computer.

After copying the source *files* and or *folders* to the **Desktop** of the destination computer, then in **Terminal**, on the destination computer, run the following *compound command*:

```
cp /path/to/copied/.DS_Store ~/Desktop; killall Finder
```

You should now see the same *layout* as on the source computer.

Comment: Indeed, it works! Restarting the Finder seems to be the key. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the terminal with commands :

On A Mac to a external drive formatted hfs or apfs

```
cp -av ~/Desktop /Volumes/Destination
```

Then on the B machine with a **User Admin** different that this one you would change the Desktop, you rename Desktop directory (with sudo) :

```
sudo mv /Users/username/Desktop /Users/username/Desktop.o
```

then you replace with the new :

```
sudo cp -a /Volumes/Destination/Desktop /Users/username
```

and affect this "Desktop" to the User "destination"

```
sudo chown -R username:staff /Users/username/Desktop
```